# Angular 8 White screen after installing font-awesome between nav and footer

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular8

I had recently installed font-awesome to put some icons on a component. As soon as after installing it, neither do the icons work, and I also lost all front-end visuals. Only the navbar shows and the footer. It compiles fine. But I see nothing else. 
I had a well-running page on http://localhost:4200/teams/1/RCB
I was trying to put those font-awesome icons into http://localhost:4200/teams/
which is team-list-component-html
First of all I would get an error like Can't bind to 'size' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("
If I remove all code from this errorful html file, I get a white blank screen on my main component which was loading on http://localhost:4200/teams/1/RCB

Tried installing and uninstalling font-awesome which gives me more errors
Checked all approutes, and everything seems fine.

team-list-component.html

```
<div class="container pt-3">
      <div class="d-block">
        <h3 class="d-inline">Teams</h3>
        <fa class="red-icon" [size]="2" [name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa>
      </div>
      <hr>
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let team of teams">
      <div class="d-block">
        <h6 class="d-inline">{{ team.team }}</h6>
        <fa class="red-icon" [name] = " 'trash' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'pencil' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'info-circle' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" [routerLink]="['/teams', team.id, team.team]"></fa>
      </div>
      <h6 class="text-muted">{{ team.description }}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

team-details-component.html

<div class="container pt-3" *ngIf="team">
  <div class="d-block">
    <h3 class="d-inline">{{team.team}}'s details</h3>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <h5>{{ team.description }}</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <app-dashboard-dock [border]="['border-primary']" [text]="['text-primary']" [title]="['Matches Played']" [value]="team.totalPlayed"></app-dashboard-dock>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <app-dashboard-dock [border]="['border-success']" [text]="['text-success']" [title]="['Matches Won']" [value]="team.totalWon"></app-dashboard-dock>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <app-dashboard-dock [border]="['border-danger']" [text]="['text-danger']" [title]="['Matches Lost']" [value]="team.totalLost"></app-dashboard-dock>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <app-dashboard-dock [border]="['border-warning']" [text]="['text-warning']" [title]="['No result']" [value]="team.noResult"></app-dashboard-dock>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="d-block">
    <h5 class="d-inline">Players</h5>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped mt-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
        <th scope="col">Mat</th>
        <th scope="col">Runs</th>
        <th scope="col">HS</th>
        <th scope="col">Ave</th>
        <th scope="col">SR</th>
        <th scope="col">Wkts</th>
        <th scope="col">Best</th>
        <th scope="col">100</th>
        <th scope="col">50</th>
        <th scope="col">4s</th>
        <th scope="col">6s</th>
        <th scope="col">CT</th>
        <th scope="col">ST</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="text-italic" *ngFor="let player of team.players">
        <th scope="row">
          {{ player.playerName}}
          <span class="text-small text-muted font-weight-light">({{player.preference}})</span>
        </th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.matchesPlayed}}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.runs }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.highestScore }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.average }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.strikeRate }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.wickets }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.bestWicket }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.centuries }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.fifties }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.fours }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.sixes }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.catches }}</th>
        <th class="font-weight-normal">{{ player.stumpings }}</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

appmodule.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './nav/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './nav/footer/footer.component';
import { TeamListComponent } from './teams/team-list/team-list.component';
import { TeamDetailsComponent } from './teams/team-details/team-details.component';
import { DashboardDockComponent } from './teams/dashboard-dock/dashboard-dock.component';
import { PlayersListComponent } from './players/players-list/players-list.component';
import { AddPlayerComponent } from './players/add-player/add-player.component';
import { AddTeamComponent } from './teams/add-team/add-team.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/teams', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'teams', component: TeamListComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id/:name', component: TeamDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'add', component: AddTeamComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: AddTeamComponent },
  { path: 'players', component: PlayersListComponent },
  { path: 'players/add', component: AddPlayerComponent },
  ]}

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TeamListComponent,
    TeamDetailsComponent,
    DashboardDockComponent,
    PlayersListComponent,
    AddPlayerComponent,
    AddTeamComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,    
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

appcomponent.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <main role="main">
    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
  </main>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

index.html

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <main role="main">
    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
  </main>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Errors:

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'size' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("
      <div class="d-block">
        <h3 class="d-inline">Teams</h3>
        <fa class="red-icon" [ERROR ->][size]="2" [name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa>
     "): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@3:29
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. (" class="d-block">
        <h3 class="d-inline">Teams</h3>
        <fa class="red-icon" [size]="2" [ERROR ->][name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa>
      </div>
  "): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@3:40
Can't bind to 'border' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("       <h3 class="d-inline">Teams</h3>
        <fa class="red-icon" [size]="2" [name] = " 'plus' " [ERROR ->][border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa>
      </div>
      <hr>
"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@3:60
Can't bind to 'pull' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. (""d-inline">Teams</h3>
        <fa class="red-icon" [size]="2" [name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [ERROR ->][pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa>
      </div>
      <hr>
"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@3:77
'fa' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <div class="d-block">
        <h3 class="d-inline">Teams</h3>
        [ERROR ->]<fa class="red-icon" [size]="2" [name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/te"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@3:8
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("v class="d-block">
        <h6 class="d-inline">{{ team.team }}</h6>
        <fa class="red-icon" [ERROR ->][name] = " 'trash' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <f"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@10:29
Can't bind to 'border' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("       <h6 class="d-inline">{{ team.team }}</h6>
        <fa class="red-icon" [name] = " 'trash' " [ERROR ->][border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" "): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@10:50
Can't bind to 'pull' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. (""d-inline">{{ team.team }}</h6>
        <fa class="red-icon" [name] = " 'trash' " [border]="false" [ERROR ->][pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'penci"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@10:67
'fa' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <div class="d-block">
        <h6 class="d-inline">{{ team.team }}</h6>
        [ERROR ->]<fa class="red-icon" [name] = " 'trash' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(tea"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@10:8
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [ERROR ->][name] = " 'pencil' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@11:31
Can't bind to 'border' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'pencil' " [ERROR ->][border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [n"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@11:53
Can't bind to 'pull' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. (")="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'pencil' " [border]="false" [ERROR ->][pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'info-ci"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@11:70
'fa' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" [name] = " 'trash' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onDeleteTeam(team)"></fa>
        [ERROR ->]<fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'pencil' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(te"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@11:8
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. (" [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [ERROR ->][name] = " 'info-circle' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" [routerLink]="['/teams', team.id, team.t"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@12:31
Can't bind to 'border' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'info-circle' " [ERROR ->][border]="false" [pull]="'right'" [routerLink]="['/teams', team.id, team.team]"></fa>
      </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@12:58
Can't bind to 'pull' since it isn't a known property of 'fa'. ("onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        <fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'info-circle' " [border]="false" [ERROR ->][pull]="'right'" [routerLink]="['/teams', team.id, team.team]"></fa>
      </div>
      <h6 class=""): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@12:75
'fa' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("" [name] = " 'pencil' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" (click)="onEditTeam(team)"></fa>
        [ERROR ->]<fa class="green-icon" [name] = " 'info-circle' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" [routerLink]="['/"): ng:///AppModule/TeamListComponent.html@12:8
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11188)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25721)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25709)
    at compiler.js:25653
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25653)
    at compiler.js:25566
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
```

Comment: Your selector should be "fa-icon" not "fa"

Answer (score 0):

Check your selector name for the FontAwesome icon.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fa-icon and also if you are giving static size then don't use One-way data binding.

It should be like this:

```
<fa-icon class="red-icon" size="2px" [name] = " 'plus' " [border]="false" [pull]="'right'" routerLink="/teams/add"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, I'm going to install font-awesome again. What do you mean by one-way data binding in this context?

Comment: The value of the size attribute is provided in the HTML itself, right? Or are you going to provide that value from the component? If it is from the HTML itself like I did in the above sample, then you do not need parenthesis ( [ ] ) along with the size attribute. If you use parenthesis, it means you are trying to provide the value from the component using some variable.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have changed the code to use <i class> </i> . The errors are gone, but i get a white screen now between the nav and footer(which display). 

I've added all imports correctly in package.json and module in appmodule.ts but still cannot understand where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot for it?